# CakePHP Auth Session variable completely missing in Chrome (on some machines)

Tags: cakephp, session-variables, session-cookies, cakephp-2.1

I can go to my site, look in DebugKit > Session, and see the "Auth" variable - works fine, and everything is great.

BUT - on two machines (out of 5-7 tested), and only in Chrome, the Auth variable is completely missing.  This keeps the user from logging in, screws up redirects...etc etc.

We've tried uninstalling and re-installing Chrome - we made sure security settings and session/cookie settings in Chrome were the same as all the other computers that work...etc etc. (Maybe we missed one?, but - fresh install, so...).   And we made sure we're all in the same version of Chrome.

At first I thought it might be an issue with my code (and it still could be), but then we tried logging into another Cake site on one of the "stupid" computers, and it did the same thing - can't log-in.

Comment: That last sentence makes it sounds like a browser issue. Have you inspected the cookies in Chrome to make sure the Cake one is being created? Is it just your Cake app that has an issue (i.e., can you log into other sites)? Is just the Auth key missing or the entire session?

Comment: Also have you tried setting checkAgent to false in your Cake Session config. It exposes you to session hijacking but try it as a process of elimination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have had something to do w/ the Security Component.  When I turned that off, they could log-in fine.

Still not sure exactly what the issue is, but upgraded my site to [CakePHP 2.2 beta](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.2), and **it's not an issue now**.

The release notes [are here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/markstory/2012/04/30/cakephp_2_1_2_2_2_0-beta_released).

Here are some of the release notes from the 2.1.2 stable release (I was on 2.1) - these are the ones that relate to Sessions/Auth...etc that COULD have had something to do with the problem:

- AuthComponent now uses loginRedirect as the default redirect location, should the session be empty.
- A change to CakeSession was reverted to help solve issues with IE8 and sessions being lost.
- SessionComponent::id() always returns the sessionid. It will auto-start the session if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to resolve exactly this issue on my machine.

It seems that somehow my Chrome managed to get two cookies with the same name for the same domain - CAKEPHP.

In order to make sure that all cookies are reset for all browsers I have updated my session configuration in `/app/Config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
            'defaults' => 'php',
            'cookieTimeout' => 0,
            'cookie' => 'newNameSESSION',
));
```

Note the key 'cookie' explicitly setting a new cookie name for the identification of the session. After this change I was able to log on to my application from all browser from which I was unable to log in before.

Comment: Awesome - Going to try this Asap!  Very much hope to be able to mark this as the answer!

Comment: Though.. why would this work/matter if I'm clearing my cookies before each attempt?

Comment: Well, if you are clearing the cookies anyway - it should not matter. But please let me know if it works.

Comment: Does not work. Same problem here. FF is good, but Chrome 24 is not. Same problem for other Session/Redirection related problems: after a redirect, in Chrome, Session vars are lost. (I use Cake 2.3 RC2. Tested also with Cake 2.2)